# asp.net For each within For each

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following:

```
    For Each dist In dtDataTableDist.Rows

      For Each det In dtDataTableDet.Rows

        If Not (det("LoginName") Is dist("LoginName")) Then Continue For

      Next
    Next
```

Within the inner For Each I have

```
     Not (det("LoginName") Is dist("LoginName")) Then Continue For
```

What I am trying to do here is to say that if the login in the inner for each is not the same 
as the LoginName in the out then skip the rest of the code in the inner loop and continue to the next inner for each.

Although the det("LoginName") and  dist("LoginName") both have the same value of "899"
I would think that it would not skip the rest of the code in the inner loop but it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is` is used for comparing **objects**... in other words are the two object references the exact same object.

You should be using normal comparison...

```
If Not (det("LoginName") = dist("LoginName")) Then Continue For
```

Or...

```
If det("LoginName") <> dist("LoginName") Then Continue For
```